# Is there any sun-color that gives humans "Kryptonian" powers?

Tags: dc, superman

Superman famously gets his powers from the light of the yellow sun, and loses them from the light of a red sun.

Is that a purely Kryptonian phenomenon, or does the "color of sunlight" have larger implications throughout the DC universe?  Is there a color of sunlight that would give a human the kind of powers that Superman has on Earth?  If not, is any explanation given (scientific or pseudo-scientific) of why Kryptonians are so profoundly affected by light, unlike other races?

Comment: Yes, rgb(255,0,255) does.

Comment: @JohnO Oooh. What a lovely magenta...

Comment: Jor El specifically says "they are a great people Kal El, they only lack the 'light' to show them the way." There is some kind of light that would give humans super powers. I am an autistic.